# Passing an interface method as a parameter

Tags: c#, wcf, asmx

**Note**: This could very well be very `C#` specific language question, unrelated to `WCF` or `web services` at all.

There is a 3-party `ASMX` web service, which shall be used for data retrieval. I have created a generalized method called `ExecuteCommand()` which is used for every request against the web service. The purpose of this method is to handle cookie session/exceptions and other common logic. For each request a new channel shall be used, in order to simplify the disposal of unused resources.

The problem is that to use the `ExecuteCommand()` method - I have to initialize a channel each time, in order to be able to pass the method to be executed as an argument. Sorry if it sounds too complicated. Here is a usage example:

```
string color = "blue";
var channel = _strategyFactory.CreateChannel<CarServiceSoapChannel>();
var cars = WcfHelper.ExecuteCommand(channel, () => channel.GetCars(color));
// channel is null here. Channel was closed/aborted, depending on Exception type.
```

After `ExecuteCommand()` is called - `channel` is already disposed of. The reason why `channel` object is needed at all, is to be able to provide a method to be executed as a parameter! i.e.`() => channel.GetCars()`. To further support these words, here is the `WcfHelper` class internals:

```
public static class WcfHelper
{
    public static Cookie Cookie { get; set; }

    public static T ExecuteCommand<T>(IClientChannel channel, Expression<Func<T>> method)
    {
        T result = default(T);

        try
        {
            // init operation context
            using (new OperationContextScope(channel))
            {
                // set the session cookie to header
                if (Cookie != null) {
                    HttpRequestMessageProperty request = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
                    request.Headers["Cookie"] = cookie.ToString();
                    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = request;  
                }

                // execute method
                var compiledMethod = method.Compile();
                result = compiledMethod.Invoke();
            }
        }
        // do different logic for FaultException, CommunicationException, TimeoutException
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseOrAbortServiceChannel(channel);
            channel = null;
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static void CloseOrAbortServiceChannel(ICommunicationObject communicationObject)
    {
        bool isClosed = false;

        if (communicationObject == null || communicationObject.State == CommunicationState.Closed)
            return;

        try
        {
            if (communicationObject.State != CommunicationState.Faulted)
            {
                communicationObject.Close();
                isClosed = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!isClosed)
                AbortServiceChannel(communicationObject);
        }
    }

    private static void AbortServiceChannel(ICommunicationObject communicationObject)
    {
        try
        {
            communicationObject.Abort();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

So the short question - it it possible to initialize a `channel` variable inside the `ExecuteCommand` method itself, while having a possibility to define, which method shall be executed inside `ExecuteCommand` for a given channel?

I am trying to accomplish something like this:

```
string color = "blue";
var cars = WcfHelper.ExecuteCommand<Car[], CarServiceSoapChannel>(channel => channel.GetCars(color));
```

or even

```
string color = "blue";
var cars = WcfHelper.ExecuteCommand<CarServiceSoapChannel>(channel => channel.GetCars(color));
```

Any other code improvement suggestions are welcomed but not mandatory, of course.

P.S. `ASMX` is added as a `Service reference` in `Visual Studio`. Therefore, there were some entities that automatically generated for the "CarService", such as - `CarServiceSoapChannel` interface, `CarServiceSoapClient` class and of course `CarService` interface containing methods of a web service. In the example above a `ChannelFactory` is used to create a channel for the `CarServiceSoapChannel` interface, hence, here is where the question name is coming from: `Passing an interface method as a parameter`. This could be a bit misleading, but I hope it's clear what I trying to accomplish from the description itself.

**Update 25.05.2018**
I followed the advice of @nvoigt and was able to achieve the result I wanted:

```
public static TResult ExecuteCommand<TInterface, TResult>(Func<TInterface, TResult> method)
    where TInterface : IClientChannel
{
    TResult result = default(TResult);
    IClientChannel channel = null;

    try
    {
        channel = StrategyFactory.CreateChannel<TInterface>();

        // init operation context
        using (new OperationContextScope(channel))
        {
            // set the session cookie to header
            if (Cookie != null)
                Cookie.SetCookieForSession();

            // execute method
            result = method((TInterface)channel);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        CloseOrAbortServiceChannel(channel);
        channel = null;
    }

    return result;
}
```

This already achieves the initial goal. There is, however, one issue with this approach. In order to call the method - you have to explicitly specify the method's return parameter.

So to say, if you want to call the method - writing this is not enough:

```
var result = WcfHelper.ExecuteCommand<CarServiceSoapChannel>(channel => channel.IsBlue())
```

You will have to specifically specify, that the return type shall be `boolean`

```
var result = WcfHelper.ExecuteCommand<CarServiceSoapChannel, bool>(channel => channel.IsBlue())
```

I personally don't mind writing an extra bit of code, as it is still a big advantage over my initial method implementation, however, I am wondering in the new version could be improved?

For example, When I had just 1 generic `TResult` type in the method - the return type `<TResult>` could be omitted. This is no longer the case with 2 generics. In any case, thank you @**nvoigt**!

Comment: The second approach seems quite decent in my eyes. You create/initialize the channel within `ExecuteCommand` and pass it as argument to the anonymous method. What´s whrong with it?

Comment: @HimBromBeere The second approach? You probably mean `var cars = WcfHelper.ExecuteCommand<CarServiceSoapChannel>(channel => channel.GetCars(color));` ? That is something I am trying to implement. A preferred way of facing this issue. The method does not work that way yet. :) hence here is the question.

Comment: All you have to do is provide the channel to the `Func` you´ve created by `compileMethod.Compile()` - assuming your func was `Func<Channel, T>`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere This worked great! Thank you for the input on this issue! *nvoigt* made a good example for this suggestion in the answer section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method signature should be:

```
public static TResult ExecuteCommand<TInterface>(Func<TInterface, TResult> method)
```

Then in your WcfHelper (which should probably not be `static` anymore because it needs a member `_strategyFactory`) you create a channel as before:

```
{
    var channel = _strategyFactory.CreateChannel<CarServiceSoapChannel>();

    return method(channel);
}
```

Obviously, you need to add all the fancy try/finally stuff again.

---

As you should have instances anyway now with the factory in the class as a member, you could put the service contract generic into your class to make it easier for users:

```
public class ConnectionToService<TInterface> : where TInterface : class
{
    public TResult ExecuteCommand<TResult>(Func<TInterface, TResult> method)
    {
        var channel = _strategyFactory.CreateChannel<CarServiceSoapChannel>();

        return method(channel);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var service = new ConnectionToService<ICarService>();

var color = service.ExecuteCommand(s => s.GetColor());
```

Comment: It seems that I have completely missed the point of using the `Expression<Func<T>> method` in my implementation.. I will need to check `Expression` vs `Func` differences. I followed your advice and refactored the code accordingly. Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to improve the method, so the `TResult` would be an implicit type? See my latest update

Comment: @Alex Last time I wrote such a class, I put the `TInterface` generic type in the class. I'll add an example.

Comment: Great! Thank you!